# Include and compile custom.less file after removing the style-l and style-m css

Tags: magento2, css, less

I am new in magneto2. I am working on LUMA theme and I have to customize it. So my approach is that I am removing all the existing i.e. `style-l.css` and `style-m.css` by writing code in the `default_head_blocks.xml` file because my design does not match with the current theme structure.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <remove src="css/styles-l.css" />
        <remove src="css/styles.css" />
   </head>
</page>
```

Now I want to create a `custom.less` file so that I can write my custom css code but don't know how to include and compile the less file now because earlier my `custom.less` file is coming inside the `style-l.css` file. But Now I have removed it. So my question is how to include and compile a `custom.less` file after removing the `style-l.css` and `style-m.css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `yourTheme/web/css/custom.less`
2. Add `<css src="css/custom.css"/>` to your `default_head_blocks.xml`

Look in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank` to see more on how Magento do this.

Comment: I think for your first point custom.css not custom.less

Comment: The question is asking about adding `custom.less`. This gets compiled to CSS which is why `custom.css` is added in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

In order to add custom css into theme and load it at last, you can go through following directory structure.

```
modulename/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css
```

Call the corresponding css file from layout file. e.g.

```
<head>
 <css src="Vendor_Module::css/custom.css"/>
 <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
 <remove src="css/styles-l.css" />
 <remove src="css/styles.css" />
</head>
```